# disable CORS checking in jsdom on nodejs

Tags: javascript, jsdom

Is it possible to disable the CORS checking functionality in the `jsdom` node module?

The CORS errors are particularly difficult to debug in my use case (clientside testing) and do not occur in the actual environment I am running the program.

Perhaps some environmental variable we can set when initializing the object? e.g.,

```
window = new jsdom.JSDOM(``,{
    cors : false,
}).window;
```

Comment: what does jsdom have to do with cors/ajax? doesn't it just mimick the DOM?

Comment: @KevinB jsdom implements XMLHttpRequest and other API's found in the browser.

Comment: Right, but why would that be throwing CORS errors?

Comment: @KevinB It allows a [url](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#simple-options) parameter to be passed as an option for which it then considers same-origin restrictions

Comment: So change the url to one that wouldn't cause cors problems? That appears to be the only relevant option.

Comment: It's more about the server not allowing you to request from a client that is not on the same origin. This [issue](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1941) seems to confirm that's it's not possible in JSDOM.

Comment: @KevinB I know there are other solutions. I'm asking if this solution is possible.

Comment: @PierreC. Thank you. Unfortunate that this is the case. If you add that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in this [issue](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1941) on JSDOM Github repository, JSDOM acts like a browser and the same-origin policy applies.

It **cannot** be disabled from there.

The solution would be to add headers to the resource server allowing the origin of the client which makes the request.

Comment: what part of the headers need to change in the jsdom config?

Comment: @electricwizard none, it has to be done on the server.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @pierre-c!

I'm using JSDOM for my Mocha test environment and AFAIK there are no server settings to speak of. My Nginx configs for example I _think_ are irrelevant.. I'm using Fetchmock (https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock) though. Should I look for configuration options over there instead?

Comment: update: actually, I suppose Nginx does apply, because otherwise I wouldnt have written this in the past. 


    const DOM = new global.jsdom.JSDOM(basicDocument, {
    // Can't use localhost here because it's blocked on testing servers
      url: 'http://example.com',
    });
    global.window = DOM.window;
    global.document = global.window.document;

Comment: The original question was about a CORS error. If you are using `fetch-mock`, it does not make any sense that this type of error appears.You probably need to write a new question to resolve your specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `testURL` in your jest.config.js to your API address.

Comment: This method should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Set `window._origin` to the requested origin such as `http://www.example.com`. Works for Jest 27.5.1.